# Python OpenCV 3.1.0 `CascadeClassifier.detectMultiScale3()` gives different bounding box

Tags: python, opencv3.1

Code:

```
cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(CASCADE_XML_PATH)

result = cascade.detectMultiScale(greyscale_image, scaleFactor=1.05, minNeighbors=1, minSize=(200, 200), flags=0)
print(result)

result2 = cascade.detectMultiScale2(greyscale_image, scaleFactor=1.05, minNeighbors=1, minSize=(200, 200), flags=0)
print(result2)

result3 = cascade.detectMultiScale3(greyscale_image, scaleFactor=1.05, minNeighbors=1, minSize=(200, 200), flags=0, outputRejectLevels=True)
print(result3)
```

The constant `CASCADE_XML_PATH` is actually `[...]/opencv-3.1.0/data/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml`, so I'm doing face detection.

Output:

```
[[ 34 339 403 403]]
(array([[ 34, 339, 403, 403]], dtype=int32), array([[49]], dtype=int32))
(array([[112, 297, 258, 258]], dtype=int32), array([[20]], dtype=int32), array([[ 56.77932617]]))
```

As you can see, `cascade.detectMultiScale()` and `cascade.detectMultiScale2()` give the same bounding box, but `cascade.detectMultiScale3()` gives a different bounding box, which is baffling. Am I doing something wrong? Has anyone else experienced this?